# How to add query operators to query of Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have problem. My app allows user to filter offers by few params.
I would like to fetch data with `.where()` operator by I need to stack them. How can I do it?

My attempt (don't work):

```
let query = db.collection("cards").where("cardId", "==", id);

  if (filterParams.price.from && filterParams.price.to) {
    query
      .where("price", ">=", filterParams.price.from)
      .where("price", "<=", filterParams.price.to);
  }
  if (filterParams.graded) {
    query.where("isGraded", "==", filterParams.graded);
  }
  if (filterParams.condition) {
    query.where("condition", "==", filterParams.condition);
  }

  query = await query.get();
```

Comment: What errors do you get on running this code?

Comment: I have no error on output, it looks like .where() isn't attached to query

Comment: Can you try changing the last line to `const snapshot = await query.get()` instead of assigning the result to query itself. I would also log `filterParams` to check if all values are as intended

Comment: filterParams has been checked, I changed const snapshot = await query.get() but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query objects are immutable. Each time you call `where` it returns a new `Query` object, which you need to then keep a reference to that query.

So:

```
let query = db.collection("cards").where("cardId", "==", id);

if (filterParams.price.from && filterParams.price.to) {
  query = query // 
    .where("price", ">=", filterParams.price.from)
    .where("price", "<=", filterParams.price.to);
}
if (filterParams.graded) {
  query = query.where("isGraded", "==", filterParams.graded); // 
}
if (filterParams.condition) {
  query = query.where("condition", "==", filterParams.condition); // 
}

query = await query.get();
```